# What is the earliest point you can attach on() event handlers (for live() behaviour)

Tags: jquery, event-handling

So this is pretty much all in the question title, what is the earliest point you can attach on() event handlers (for live() behaviour) ?

To detail further..

I'm aware of the `ready()` event jquery pattern but according to some ([reference](http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/)) you don't really have to wait for everything to be ready to attach events if you use things like `live()`.

`live()` is now deprecated in favour of `on()` which does a somewhat similar behaviour.

However `live()` used to attach the events to `$(document)` which sounds like it would be available way early in the document parsing.

`on()` on the other hand is usually recommended to use by attaching the event to something a little closer to the target in the DOM.

So if I've got most of my content inside a `#main` section, `$('#main')` would be a good candidate for attach `on()` handler.

With that in mind, when is it safe to attach my `on()` handler?

Is it as soon at the container tag open? or once it's closed?

Is this reliable and generally behaves correctly across browsers ?

```
<html>
<!-- boring head stuff goes here (including loading jquery, obviously) -->
<body>

    <header>Stuff</header>

    <section id='main'>
        <script>
            $('#main').on('click','button.donkey', function() { alert ('you click the donkey');})
        </script>
        ...

        <button class="donkey">Donkey That!</button>
    </section>

    <footer>Other stuff</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure once it's opened it'll be fine. However, scripts truncate page loading when encountered so I'd prefer a more unobtrusive approach, placing all your scripts right before the `</body>`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Maybe put that as an answer..

Comment: I would be grateful if someone had researched this and cross checked on multiple browsers..

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't post as an answer. I've tested on FF/Chrome/Opera/IE6-9 in the past but then you never know if there are certain corner cases. It'd be better to wait for a more well-funded answer. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté. Fair enough. Thanks for the FF/...IE6-9 report. I'd be interested to know if anyone has tried these on mobile browsers..

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the event as soon as the element is attached to the dom. Since `.on()` is now responsible for all types of event-attachment (direct attachment as well as delegates) you should not attach the events before the child-element is declared but rather at the end of your `#main` to stay consistent. Since in general it is recommended to put your scripts as late as possible, i would go with the following:

```
<section id='main'>
    ...
    <button class="donkey">Donkey That!</button>
</section>
<script>
    $('#main').on('click','button.donkey', function() { alert ('you click the donkey');})
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have anything that backs that claim or is it just gut feeling?

Comment: Seems to work on Chrome if it's inside the #main tag.. not sure about the different browsers

Comment: @Ben you can read more about it in the [tree construction section of the html-docs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tree-construction.html#tree-construction). It should not matter, but I think it's safer to do it after the closing tag in terms of cross-browser campatibility and differences between elements (optional closing/non-closing tags and so on) and different functionalities of the `on()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the ref. Which part of it indicates that you have to wait until the element is closed to start using it?